# convection microwave that also broils

Tags: convection, broiling

How do convection microwaves that also broil work?  I am researching (SharpR1874 and Sharp R1881LSY) such ovens that boast a broil feature.  One clearly states it has an element in the top, the other never does say, only convection heating distributed by a fan.  So, do they both  have an element?

Comment: It probably has a resistance for broiling function.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking the same element is used for both broil (grill here in the UK) and convection.  In the latter mode a fan distirbutes the heat evenly around the oven, but for tall items in particulart the top heat from the element can be a little fierce.  I've got 2 Panasonics that work this way, and when investigating those all major rivals seemed to be the same.